# Permutations and Combinations Olympiad

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Suppose that all positive integers which are relatively prime to 105 are arranged in an increasing sequence  -  a1 , a2 ,a3 ,....

Evaluate a1000.

Comment: Please add your own thoughts and ideas to the body of your question.That way,more people will want to help you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\varphi(105)=(3-1)\cdot(5-1)\cdot(7-1)={48}$, so $a_{48}=104$. Then, $a_{48k}=105k-1$.